# Colors from PS5 - WebM files are washed out after uploading on YouTube, can ffmpeg fix it?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, webm, playstation, yuv

Can I repair or change the color command via "ffmepg" without re-encoding the file?

There seems to be a communication problem between the created *.webm file from the PlayStation 5 and YouTube and so the color range is not correct. [Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLzV3.jpg)

The colors are correct when played via the PS5 itself or via the windows media player or vlc player.

As a test I tried the following via ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i *.webm -vf format=yuv420p -dst_range 1 -color_range 2 -c:v mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale 1 -y *.avi
```

then I had the original colors.

On the other hand, in the video editing program Davinci Resolve 18, the color is immediately displayed incorrectly.
As an example, I change the container via FFMPEG from *.webm to *.mp4 and can then simply set the clip attributes "Data Levels" from "Auto/Full" to "Video" in the Davinci Resolve program, then the video will be in the normal colors displayed.

ffmpeg -i of the raw file:

```
ffmpeg version 2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavcodec     60. 21.100 / 60. 21.100
  libavformat    60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  8.102 /  9.  8.102
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : mkvmux-1.0.0
  Duration: 00:00:11.31, start: -0.003000, bitrate: 46767 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
  Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

maybe I'll finally find help here, with YouTube and Sony/PlayStation itself, you can't get the right support with the problem/bug and the problem is only pushed to the other.

UPDATE 03.07.2023: I think/hope found the solution.
After I compared both files via MediaInfo [SCREENSHOT MediaInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMO9.jpg), I noticed the following:

```
Color range : Limited
colour_range_Original : Full
```

changed to:

```
color range : Full
colour_range_Original : Limited
```

Used the command:

```
ffmpeg -i *.webm -bsf:v vp9_metadata=color_range=tv -c copy *.webm
```

and now, after uploading to YouTube, the video is with the normal colors.
Where is the error here, in the created file (PS5) or reading the file (YouTube and Davinci Resolve)

Comment: I think I found the solution.
After I compared both files via MediaInfo, I noticed the following: 
`Color range : Limited
colour_range_Original : Full`
changed to:
`color range : Full
colour_range_Original : Limited`
Used the command: `ffmpeg -i *.webm -bsf:v vp9_metadata=color_space=bt709:color_range=tv -c copy *.webm` 
and now, after uploading to YouTube, the video is with the normal colors. 
Where is the error here, in the created file (PS5) or reading the file (YouTube and Davinci Resolve)